# didUpdateLocations called only once and then stops firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location

I want to make a simple IOS 6.0 application that shows the lat/lon on screen each time the location is changed. The ViewController files are pretty trivial.

I alloc a CCLocationManager objec, set its variables and start it.
didUpdateLocations is called once or twice and then it stops being fired, even if the iPhone is moved. If I press Home button and reopen the app, the data on screen is updated once or twice before it stops again.
At simulation it works fine but not on a real 3GS iPhone.

If I uncomment the start/stop inside didUpdateLocations and continuously stop and start the service, it works, but the battery gets drained in extreme rates.

Also, this is part of a much bigger project and didUpdateLocations **must** be called each time the location is changed.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic , strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
@end
```

**ViewConroller.m**

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

`@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone; // whenever we move
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
_locationManager.PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf %lf",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
//[_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
//[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
@end`

If there's any advice on what's wrong, I would welcome it, I have lost a week already without solving it.

BTW, I have tested various values for the _locationManager variables but without any chnage in the behaviour

Additional info:
application is authorized to use location services
application is in foreground

Comment: One thing - change `kCLHeadingFilterNone` to `kCLDistanceFilterNone`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Add `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` to your class. And, is that all your code in the view controller? If not, please add all.

Comment: I added the delegate at .h, with no effect. Yes, this is all the code in the view controller. I made it as simple as possible to reproduce the error. Is it maybe a hardware error? I might try to check it on another iPhone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few tips for similar issues as per my experience with location-based programming on iOS.

- If it works on simulator, then it should work on actual device as
  well.
- Unlike simulator, the actual device will only give update when its receives new information from GPS.
- There are many cases where you won't get enough/required updates on a device, like when you are in a building (or covered area)
- Try testing the app in open space (GPS works much better in open space rather than room/house/large-building).

PS. I don't know how much you moved but just to let you know, moving few steps doesn't make sure you will get a new location update, try using it on some vehicle (bike/car/bus).

Comment: thank you for your info. As it seems, the GPS works but not as often as I wanted it. Of course, testing it in a room doesn't help either. I decided to bypass the problem, by stoppping/starting the location Update when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too — the easiest fix is simply to duplicate the target. You can then delete the original target.

It seems the problem occurs with older Xcode projects, not newly created ones.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this call to your code:

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```